# Glitch dotted lines in HTML Canvas using translate and scale

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to do a canvas where you can draw a line with your mouse and this line is being mirrored while drawing. So at the end you got a symmetry drawing effect. I wrote a draw function and included the transform and scale attribute. Sadly now the line has small little gaps and is not fluent anymore.

```
function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);

    ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0);
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);  

    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

}
```

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7UIc.png)

Without the translate() and scale() attribute the line is clear, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ACT.png). Do you have any idea why the line is dotted and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because every time you move the mouse, you are only drawing one line, either "normal" or "mirrored" but not both. You can see that your "dots" actually correspond to the dashes of the other side.

The switching happens because you apply the canvas transform once per draw call, but don't reset it, so at first mouse move, you mirror the context and at second one you'll finally draw mirrored and then switch back for the next move.

To do what you want, you could keep all your points in an Array, clear your context at the beginning of every frame and redraw the lines completely twice, once normal, and once mirrored.

```
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  // trace in normal mode
  points.forEach(({x, y}) => ctx.lineTo(x, y));
  // mirror
  ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0);
  ctx.scale(-1, 1);  
  // move to first point so we can paint in a single path
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  // trace all the points mirrored
  points.forEach(({x, y}) => ctx.lineTo(x, y));
  // paint
  ctx.stroke();
  // reset the context transform
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great comment. Learned a lot. Now I getting the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: points is not defined at HTMLDocument.draw` points is correctly defined?

Comment: At beginning `var points = [];` should be correct? Now it can't find x.

Comment: You have to store your points inside this Array from your mouse event. You don't show how you handle this event, but basically it's where you were assigning `currX` and `currY`, you'd do `points.push({x: currX, y: currY})`

Comment: a thank you very much!!! ;) it worked! One last question, is it now possible to change the way the image is flipped? so it's flipped at the x-axis instead of the y-axis?

Comment: Sure just change the translate to move on the y axis, and the scale to affect the y axis instead of the x axis `ctx.translate(0, canvas.height); ctx.scale(1, -1);`

Comment: Perfect, I tried that but forgot to but the 0 before canvas height. Thanks! One final final question :P When I now try to dynamically change the color by giving `ctx.strokeStyle = colorvar;` a variable (`colorvar = 'green';`) it changes the strokes which are also drawn before. So I'm not able to draw with two colors in one canvas anymore. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: If you need each section of the path to have a different color, then you'd need to create objects representing these sections which will have their own array of points and store these objects inside the array (so you'd have two levels of arrays). Then you'd draw each segment on its own (starting with beginPath and ending with stroke()). I lack time to write you an example now but if you can't figure this out I'll provide one tomorrow or so.

Comment: I was thinking about something similiar, but the idea was like a color picker at the side and then whenever you changed the `strokeStyle` by clicking on the button the next drawn line is in that color and so on. Like paint. :P I'm trying it myself, but if you got a clue, feel free to post it. I'm just starting out with canvas in js so I'm thnakful for your great support. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks alot!!! Great starting point for me to dig in. Are you available for hire, asking for a friend. :P